# Filtering my products on drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, search

I have imported 5.000 products to my drupal-commerce website.I want the user to be able to navigate fast on all of these products,so I just figured out that I need to make somehow a filter or a search that when the user chooses/selects some of the features of the product the result will be only the products with these features.How can I manage to do this on Drupal 7 and Drupal Commerce(Commerce kickstart?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the view.

Select a filter criteria for example "size", then click on expose filter.

This permit you create a custom search box as well clicking on "exposed filter in block" under Advanced in view.

First part of a tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-sKG1bplx0

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Views to reach filter functionality.

But, it seems, there is a [simpler solution](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api).

See video from module desription.
http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-search-api